# Brakeman: model attribute used in file name warnings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, brakeman

I'm setting file name like 'abc_1.pdf' where '1' is the value of a model's attribute. But brakeman scanner take this as security issue. I need to keep track of files by referencing file name with model attribute. Can you please tell me, what is the right way to fix this security issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

See answer [here](https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman/issues/337) by the gem owner

> Brakeman assumes any information in the database is potentially dangerous. This may not be true - perhaps in your application the value used in the file name cannot be set by the user. Also, it may be that your application makes sure to sanitize or restrict the value, which Brakeman cannot know about. Brakeman can only produce warnings about potentially dangerous code, which means there will always be some false positives.
>
> As far as I know, there is no standard way to safely access files from Rails when using untrusted input. Dangerous values include "." and "/" which can be used for directory traversal attacks.
>
> I am afraid I cannot tell you how to fix this issue because it depends on your application and you will have to determine if it is actually an exploitable vulnerability or not. Sorry!

I guess that means add this warning to the ignore file if you are sure about your code

Answer (score 0):

i don't know the Brakeman gem but you can use a bijective transformation to append your referencing model attributes to the filename so Brakeman does not worry about.

Or you can generate some kind of unique hashkey for your model attribute which is stored somewhere (else) along with the model attribute so you can look up later the model attribute then presenting the hashkey.

Comment: Nope. Brakeman still complains that a "Parameter value [is] used in file name".

Answer (score 0):

You could sanitize model attribute when generating file name

```
"abc_#{sanitize(@mymodel.some_attribute)}.pdf"
```

I think we could find even better solution if you post exact code example.

Comment: Nope. Brakeman still complains that a "Parameter value [is] used in file name"